# Why this line is executing in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Got a query from a collegue. I am not able to answer this question.

```
var x = '9'; // Line no 1
x=='7' // Line no 2
//doing something with x
```

Line no 2 is not giving any error.

another scenario

```
var x == '7';
```

Browser :
    SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

This is because the assignment is always done by single '='.

Question :

1. How first scenario executes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x == '7'
```

This line is a boolean expression. Its value is calculated and simply discarded. It is encouraged by some people to use yoda-conditions

```
if(7 == x)
```

instead of

```
if(x == 7)
```

So that you don't accidentally type `if(x = 7)` and get yourself a hard to find bug.

This

```
var x == '7'
```

on the other hand, is supposed to be a variable declaration, so the `==` operator is illegal here.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript sees `x=='7'` as `(x=='7')`.

Basically you have :

```
var x = '9'; // Line no 1
false;
//doing something with x
```

The Js engine evaluate `false`. Then move to the next instruction.

Answer (score 0):

== is not an assignement, it's a boolean expression.

I suspect the browser sees that the return value is never used, and optimized by not even execute this bit.

Which browser (or interpreter) do you use ?

Comment: "browser sees that the return value is never used, and optimized by not even execute this bit." Whether this statement is true for javascript or browser. I am a Java developer and i will not do the same in java. It shows compilation error. This is what i thought so it is an example of "week typing"